# combining 2 lines with different independent variables in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two sets of x and y variables. The x variables are not the same or else I would just add the y vectors and plot vs. x, but instead I would like to merge these two vectors by summing them somehow... Any help would be appreciated. Simply plotting them together is not enough, they must be combined.

Simple example:

```
x1 = [1, 3, 5]
y1 = [1, 2, 3]
x2 = [6, 4, 2]
y2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to plot `y1 + y2` but I have not been able to figure out any ways of doing this yet.

Comment: So... [addition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plus.html)?

Comment: addition won't work since the components of the y vectors correspond to different x values... I need to combine the LINEs made by plotting the two figures...

Comment: I have found this resource that sums up the exact problem I'm tackling, I will post a solution if this works for me. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/37326

Comment: You need to clarify your question, "merge" and "sum" are very different processes...

Comment: I need to do both... merge the two and plot their sum.\

Comment: I am using the code from the source above and I am getting an error, Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in sum_lines (line 5)
Xmax(n)=max(X{n}); 

any ideas? my x axis is all real and positive...

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/37326 :

"Hi,
A problem will arise when the x values of the graphs are not the
same. You than have to interpulate the graphs before the summation.
Here is a small program that will do it:

```
h=findobj(gca,'type','line'); % assuming there is only one figure exist or %the interesting figure is in focus
for n=1:length(h)
X{n}=get(h(n),'Xdata');
Xmin(n)=min(X{n});
Xmax(n)=max(X{n});
Y{n}=get(h(n),'Ydata');
end
xstart=max(Xmin); xstop=min(Xmax);
x=linspace(xstart,xstop,100); %you can put any other number of points
for n=1:length(h)
y(n,:)=interp1(X{n},Y{n},x);
end
ynew=sum(y,1);
hold on
plot(x,ynew,'k');
```

You may need to debug the code.

Joe
BSTEX - Equation viewer for Matlab"

Comment: getting an error, Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. Error in sum_lines (line 5) Xmax(n)=max(X{n}); please help

Comment: This is not an answer. This should have been an edit to your original question.

Comment: this is an answer, the error only came up since i had a variable already named 'max'. After changing that this worked beautifully.